# Bootstrap modal data is not getting clean after clicking on close button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a new user modal which creates new user.
[image]
When user does not provide usename and password it simly throw error message as shown in the image.

But when I click on close button, the pop get close as expected
But when I click on add new user the pop appeared with same error message.

same thing happen, text-box have some value as shown in bellow image.

[image]

I guess my close button is not destroying the data.
here is my code for close button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

if required I will post the whole code for pop.
do I need to write a separate method to clean the data? 
please help me

jsfiddle

[Please click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrunkenCooder/2mg4abu9/)

Comment: what about a `.click` event that clears the input boxes when you close?

Comment: Ok that is what I am asking do I need to write a separate method to clean the data? I really dont have idea, I am working first time on validation, no idea about all this

Comment: Use [`x.bs.modal` event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events). And yes, you should clean your fields manually.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, already bootstrap modal has a close event. You need to bind it to it.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something…
});
```

So for your case:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $("#myModal input").val("");
   $(".text-error").hide();
});
```

Have a look at the [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

Comment: I am able to hide the text box value but how do I hide the error message

Comment: Doesn't `$(".text-error").hide();` work? What class are you using for the error?

Comment: I am using bootstrap validation and I checked it in console it has error class

Comment: but when I did this   $(".error").hide();  every thing is getting disappeared except label

Comment: Okay, then replace `$(".text-error").hide();` with `$(".error").hide();`

Comment: shoud I add my validation code in question ?? I tried all this but did not work

Comment: @varun Better da... Put up a fiddle and explain your issue na?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87594/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-varun).

Answer (score 2):

For the button:

```
<button id ="close_modal" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#close_modal").click(function() {
        $('#input_id_1').val('');//these should be the id of your inputs
        $('#input_id_2').val('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes. Close button just hides the dialog and does not modify the content. You have to write additional code to clean the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear textbox data and hide validation error message on modal hide.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $("#txtboxId").val("");
   $(".errorClass").hide();
});
```